# How to return multiple values from JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a function that is validating form input, and I need to return the validated values. Right now, I'm using `if else` clauses to call individual validators, so my function returns just the first validated field (`age`), but I want to return `age`, `lastName`, and `firstName` to the calling function.

How can I get multiple values to be returned?

```
validationForm(numberOfPassengers){
    for (let i=0; i < numberOfPassengers; i++) {
      let firstName = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs['firstName'+typeOfPassenger+i]).value;
      let lastName = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs["lastName"+typeOfPassenger+i]).value
      let age = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs['age'+typeOfPassenger+i]).value;
      let regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$/;
      let resultFirstName = firstName.match(regex);
      let resultLastName = firstName.match(regex);
      if(age <= 0){
        ('.age-alignment').addClass('error-border');
      }else{
        return age;
      };
      if(resultFirstName){
        return firstName;
      }else{
        ('.first-name').addClass('error-border');
      };
      if(resultLastName){
        return lastName;
      }else{
        ('.last-name').addClass('error-border');
      };
    }
  }
```

Comment: don't manipulate the DOM manually if you use React.

Comment: can u please elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript has no notion of returning multiple objects from a functions.  Instead you'll have to build up an object that itself contains these values:

```
  var returnObject = {};
  if(age <= 0){
    ('.age-alignment').addClass('error-border');
  }else{
    returnObject.age = age;
  };
  if(resultFirstName){
    returnObject.firstName = firstName;
  }else{
    ('.first-name').addClass('error-border');
  };
  if(resultLastName){
    returnObject.lastName = lastName;
  }else{
    ('.last-name').addClass('error-border');
  };
  return returnObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify the logic.  There is also no reason to add an else statement if it's not needed.  Also, see how I'm calling a second function with the variables you want to pass as arguments.

```
function other_function(age,last_name, first_name){
        console.log("I have access to all of these:",age,last_name,first_name)
    }

validationForm(numberOfPassengers){
    for (let i=0; i < numberOfPassengers; i++) {
      let firstName = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs['firstName'+typeOfPassenger+i]).value;
      let lastName = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs["lastName"+typeOfPassenger+i]).value
      let age = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs['age'+typeOfPassenger+i]).value;
      let regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$/;
      let resultFirstName = firstName.match(regex);
      let resultLastName = firstName.match(regex);
      if(age <= 0){
        ('.age-alignment').addClass('error-border');
      }
      if(!resultFirstName){
        ('.first-name').addClass('error-border');
      };
      if(!resultLastName){
        ('.last-name').addClass('error-border');
      }
      return other_function(age,first_name,last_name)
    }
  }
```